# Wavelength of a baseball in the context of wave-particle duality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, estimation, wave-particle-duality, wavelength

This MIT professor teaches wave-particle duality of matter [here on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Qg7pQ_CYaIQ?t=1452). The formula is:

```
wavelength = h/mv
```

Her conclusion is that the wavelength is too small to be detected. Well, I can always make the speed `v` small enough so that the wavelength is 1 meter.

In the context of wave-particle duality, what does 1 meter wavelength of a baseball mean? What can you observe?

Comment: What is the required speed?

Comment: A baseball is not a coherent quantum system and therefore does not have a specific wavelength: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done the maths, but I suspect that were you to calculate the speed you would find it to be infinitely smaller than the jiggling of the atoms in the ball due to their temperature. In any case, the wave particle characteristics of the ball would in fact be the composite of the characteristics of its constituent particles, and since they would be randomly out of phase with each other you might consider it unlikely that the ball itself has an identifiable wavelike characteristic.

Comment: The required speed is indeed very small, i.e., $4.7 * 10^{-33}$. I believe you are right.